# boundary mode not supported

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

So im currently doing an image classification implementation [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fZFkqo9fMT4&ab_channel=CharismaRiyan), and I'm using CNN to implement the model
the CNN architecture is as follows :

```
model=tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    #first layer an input layer a shape of 100*150 RGP array of pictures 
    # 2D convutional layer with 32 nodes 3*3 filter
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation='relu',input_shape=(100,150,3)),
    #2d maxpooling with size of 2*2
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    
    #second layer
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    
    #third layer 
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128,(3,3),activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    
    #forth layer 
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256,(3,3),activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    
    #flatten layer 
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    
    #dense layer 
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512,activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(3,activation='softmax')
    
    
]
    
)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Now when I run the `fit` I get this error.

```
history=model.fit(train_gen,steps_per_epoch=25,epochs=20,
                  validation_data=validation_gen,validation_steps=5,verbose=2,
                  callbacks=[my_callback()]
    
)
```

The error traced back as follows

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\rabee\OneDrive\Desktop\rps-final-dataset\rbs_classification.ipynb Cell 20 in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 model.fit(train_gen,steps_per_epoch=25,epochs=20,
      2                   validation_data=validation_gen,validation_steps=5,verbose=2,
      3                   callbacks=[my_callback()]
      4     
      5 )

File c:\Users\rabee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py:67, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     65 except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
     66   filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
---> 67   raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     68 finally:
     69   del filtered_tb

File c:\Users\rabee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\scipy\ndimage\_interpolation.py:574, in affine_transform(input, matrix, offset, output_shape, output, order, mode, cval, prefilter)
    572     npad = 0
    573     filtered = input
--> 574 mode = _ni_support._extend_mode_to_code(mode)
    575 matrix = numpy.asarray(matrix, dtype=numpy.float64)
    576 if matrix.ndim not in [1, 2] or matrix.shape[0] < 1:

File c:\Users\rabee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\scipy\ndimage\_ni_support.py:54, in _extend_mode_to_code(mode)
     52     return 6
     53 else:
---> 54     raise RuntimeError('boundary mode not supported')

RuntimeError: boundary mode not supported
```

I can't understand the problem `boundary mode not supported` and how to fix it?

Comment: There might be some issues with ImageDataGenerator construction. Write the ImageDataGenerator code, please.

Comment: Can I see your train_gen? I think there is some problem with ImageDataGenerator

Answer (score 4):

I got the same error, and later I found that I have misspelled "fill_mode" parameter in train_datagen after correcting that it's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Check your ImageDataGenerator code. If your `fill_mode` parameter is set to `True`, change it to either of the following:

1. `fill_mode='nearest'`
2. `fill_mode='constant'`
3. `fill_mode='reflect'`
4. `fill_mode='wrap'`

Answer (score 0):

I'm have the exact same error message working on a CNN tutorial on Coursera. First thrown by model(fit), then keras.utils, then scipy.ndimage.

It is running on Colab, not locally on Python 3.7.1.

Not wanting to hijack the OPs thread,but would love to know what the solution turned out to be. For the record I've inserted my ImageDataGenerator code below. Please delete if inappropriate.

validation_generator =validation_datagen.flow_from_directory( directory=VALIDATION_DIR, batch_size=20, class_mode='binary', target_size=(150, 150))

Comment: OK, solved it! The validation_datagen code I was using had a capitalised class_mode argument: 'Binary' not 'binary'